# STM32: Unable to successfully load BLE firmware because of FUS_IMAGE_NOT_AUTHENTIC so my code is failing in SHCI_C2_BLE_Init()

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, stm32cubemx

I have a custom board with an STM32WB55CEU (512K Flash) that is failing to start the BLE stack on CPU2 in the function SHCI_C2_BLE_Init(). I believe it's failing this function because it failed to load the BLE firmware (stm32wb5x_BLE_Stack_full_fw v1.13.0) correctly. Whenever I try to load the firmware I get an error at the end saying FUS_IMAGE_NOT_AUTHENTIC or FUS_STAE_IMG_NOT_AUTHENTIC depending on whether I try it from the command line over USB or through the GUI over SWD. I can delete the firmware image without error and my FUS appears to be up to date and running before I attempt the update.

[Firmware Update Screen from STM32CubeProgrammer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIZEk.png)

[Security Configuration Option bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nznnw.png)

I've also tried deleting the firmware by changing the RDP register from AA to BB and back. I still get the authentication error. This only happens on about half of the boards that I've loaded (13 out of 25). I feel like there is an address of setting somewhere that I'm not setting correctly and since all of the other posts I can find on this issue use the Nucleo with the 1MB flash part I'm not sure if my parts settings should be different. I am putting the FUS and BLE firmware at the correct address for my part according the v1.13 release notes.

Any help to get past this authentication issue would be appreciated. Thanks.